# iterate over array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Ok, so I've read loads of articles and I think I'm at risk of duplicating, but cant work this one out.

I have an array that is being returned by a PHP function, I've called it getLeague();

The structure of the array is:

> body[0]->position
>
> body[0]->teamname
>
> body[0]->points

and obviously the results increment from 0 -16 as that's the amount of teams in my league.

I'm trying to tabulate the array by calling getLeague() and iterating over the returned array to print into a table.

I'm trying at the minute to work out the basic for each loop, after that I'll shoehorn it into a table. Can you help me with the foreach? I've tried:

```
<table class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 

        <?php
        $rows = getLeague();
        foreach ($rows as $row):
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row->body->position; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->body->teamname; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->body->points; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <? endforeach ?>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you encounter an error? What didn't work?

Comment: You're using object access syntax, but are calling these items an array. Seems like the first is an array. Are the items actually objects or are they arrays? Which it is depends on how you're getting them from the DB

Comment: Could you add the output of var_dump($rows); to your question?

Comment: You haven't shown an array at any point or anything "obvious" or clear. It would be more helpful to show php code for a php question than HTML.

Comment: with all due respect there's plenty of php in my question, its just that i use it in a html context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more on that data structure, I can't say for certain, but I think you want:

```
foreach ($rows->body as $row):
```

And:

```
$row->position
```